# How do I set variables to true/false from a Listview of Checkboxes?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, checkbox

I created a listview with a custom adapter that allows me to have a list of items with checkboxes next to each item.

So I would like to look at the checkbox for the corresponding item in the list and see if it is checked and if it is, then set the value of boolean whiskey = false to true and so on for the other booleans.

It is very possible I have code in the wrong class or xml file, I've been trying to piece together things I've found on the internet. I'm new to android studio so its proving very difficult. I do have about a years worth of java experience though. I have all my code written in a working program on Eclipse, I am just having a hell of a time figuring out how to implement it into a working app.

Thanks in advance.

> customAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class customAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
private Context context;

public customAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {

    return list.get(pos);
}
public void setChecked(boolean isChecked){

}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity2_listview, null);
    }

    //Handle TextView and display string from your list
    TextView label = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label);
    label.setText(list.get(position));

    //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
    CheckBox callchkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb);



    callchkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            //update isChecked value to model class of list at current position
            list.get(position).setChecked(isChecked);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
```

> Main2Activity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


boolean Whiskey, Bourbon, Rum, Gin, Vodka, Tequila = false;



String [] userIngredients = {"Whiskey", "Bourbon", "Rum", "Gin", "Vodka", "Tequila", "Club Soda", "Lemon-Lime Soda",
"Ginger ale", "Cola", "Still mineral water", "Tonic Water", "Orange Juice", "Cranberry Juice", "Grapefruit Juice",
"Tomato Juice", "Cream or Half and Half", "Milk", "Ginger Beer", "PineApple Juice", "Lemons", "Limes", "Oranges"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userIngredients);

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(userIngredients));


    listView.setAdapter(new customAdapter(list, Main2Activity.this));

}


        }
```

> activity_main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Main2Activity"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="419dp"
    android:layout_height="558dp"
    android:id="@+id/userIngredients"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="731dp"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="411dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="374dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="Check Your Ingredients"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:fontFamily="@font/cinzel"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> activity2_listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="323dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="ingredient"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do it with a BaseAdapter as well, but i suggest to use a RecyclerView instead.

I used support-v4 and recyclerview-v7 libs as following:
(Make sure that you are not developing AndroidX - check your gradle.properties of the entire project. It is very similar but uses other libraries though.)

> build.gradle

```
   android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
  ...
    dependencies {
     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
     implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
     implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
     implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
     implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
   ...
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check Your Ingredients"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

        android:id="@+id/recycler_chooser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

In the activity2_listview you might want to do more design to the xml. It looks very basic now.

> activity2_listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listviewtextlabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="ingredient"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/listviewcheckbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

In the main class we implement a callback-listener for our custom `onItemAction` function. We pass the listener with `adapter.setActionListener(this);` and add the adapter to the RecyclerViewer.

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CustomAdapter.ItemActionListener {

    boolean Whiskey, Bourbon, Rum, Gin, Vodka, Tequila = false;



    String [] userIngredients = {"Whiskey", "Bourbon", "Rum", "Gin", "Vodka", "Tequila", "Club Soda", "Lemon-Lime Soda",
            "Ginger ale", "Cola", "Still mineral water", "Tonic Water", "Orange Juice", "Cranberry Juice", "Grapefruit Juice",
            "Tomato Juice", "Cream or Half and Half", "Milk", "Ginger Beer", "PineApple Juice", "Lemons", "Limes", "Oranges"};

    CustomAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    RecyclerView recyclerListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            recyclerListView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_chooser);

            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList(userIngredients));

            // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
            // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
            recyclerListView.setHasFixedSize(false);

            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            recyclerListView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

            System.out.println("list.size() " + list.size());

            adapter = new CustomAdapter(list,MainActivity.this);
            adapter.setActionListener(this);
            recyclerListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // callback listener for your items
    @Override
    public void onItemAction(View view, CustomAdapter.CustomActions customAction, int position) {
        final String itemName = adapter.getItem(position);
        System.out.println(customAction + ": You clicked " + itemName + " on row number " + position);

        switch(itemName){
            case "Whiskey":
                if(customAction== CustomAdapter.CustomActions.CHECK){
                    Whiskey=true;
                }
                else{
                    Whiskey=false;
                }
                System.out.println("Whiskey set to: " + Whiskey);
                break;
            case "Bourbon":
                if(customAction== CustomAdapter.CustomActions.CHECK){
                    Bourbon=true;
                }
                else{
                    Bourbon=false;
                }
                System.out.println("Bourbon set to: " + Bourbon);
                break;
                //case xyz
                  //  and so on
            default:
                System.out.println("Not programmed yet: " + itemName);
        }
    }
}
```

As said above i removed the BaseAdapter and replaced it with the RecyclerView. We had to implement a custom ViewHolder-class that contains each row in our RecyclerViewList. Within the ViewHolder we can call the method on our listener whenever a checkbox-change event occurs.

> CustomAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

    //------ helper class for the viewholder
    enum CustomActions{
        CHECK,UNCHECK
    }
    // Provide a reference to the views for each row
    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mTextView;
        public CheckBox mCheckBox;

        public CustomViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            // the view element v is the whole linear layout element
            CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener checkboxListenerForOneEntry =  new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (mItemActionListener != null) {
                        if(isChecked){
                            // this compoundbutton view element will be the checkbox
                            mItemActionListener.onItemAction(view, CustomActions.CHECK, getAdapterPosition());
                        }else{
                            mItemActionListener.onItemAction(view, CustomActions.UNCHECK, getAdapterPosition());
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            mTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.listviewtextlabel);
            mCheckBox = v.findViewById(R.id.listviewcheckbox);
            mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkboxListenerForOneEntry);
        }
    }
    //------

    private ArrayList<String> list;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemActionListener  mItemActionListener;

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setActionListener(ItemActionListener itemActionListener) {
        this.mItemActionListener = itemActionListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemActionListener {
        void onItemAction(View view, CustomActions customAction, int position);
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity2_listview, parent, false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(v);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        holder.mTextView.setText(list.get(position));
    }

    @Override // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    public int getItemCount() {
        return getCount();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public String getItem(int pos) {
        return list.get(pos);
    }
}
```

Feel free to use the code as you like.

For more info about the RecyclerView see the google docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it

Comment: Could you mark my answer so others see that your question is solved? thanks